# Test Python 3 Django app in Gitlab which calls out to Python 2 shell

Tags: python, django, gitlab

I want to run my tests in a GitLab CI pipeline for a Python 3 Django app which occasionally calls out to run a Python 2 Django management script.  How do set up **both** a Python 3 and Python 2 environment (both with Django and other packages) inside the **one** GitLab CI pipeline?

Here is my current `.gitlab-ci.yml` which runs my tests in Python 2.

```
test:
  script:
  - export I_AM_ON_GITLAB_CI=1
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python manage.py test
```

I want to upgrade this to allow running the tests in Python 3 with occasional calls (shelling out via `proc = subp.Popen(cmd_array, stdout=tfil, stderr=subp.STDOUT)` etc) to Python 2.

Why do I need this? I need to run ALSM Python parsing that supports both python 2 and python 3 syntax, hence the need for two pythons in the one pipeline.  See also my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553602/deploy-python-3-django-app-in-heroku-which-calls-out-to-python-2-shell) re hosting an app with both Python 3 and Python 2 avaiable in the one app, on Heroku.